# ggplot2 fill gaps by joining a line and no symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data, line-plot

I would like to have a chart that connects missing points by a line, but not show a symbol at the missing point. Here is some code that creates some test data and produces a chart, but I would like a (id=B) green line joining points 4 and 6 with a straight line, but no green triangle at time 5. I did try `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`, but nothing much changed. Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x <- rep(seq(1:10), 3)
y <- c(runif(10), runif(10) + 1, runif(10) + 2)
group <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10))

df <- data.frame(cbind(group, x, y))
df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)
df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)
df[15,]$y <- NA

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=group))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape=group))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:3)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by removing rows where y is `NA`:

```
df2 <- df[!is.na(df$y), ]

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=group))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape=group))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:3)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# form some data
set.seed(1)
x <- rep(seq(1:10), 3)
y <- c(runif(10), runif(10) + 1, runif(10) + 2)
group <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10))

df <- tibble(group=group, x = x, y = y)

# add an NA
df[15,]$y <- NA

# plot with a gap where the NA is
p1 <-  # p1 fails because of NA 
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=group))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape=group))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:3)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# plot with no gap
p2 <- p1 %+% {df %>% na.omit()}  # p2 does what you want

p1

p2
```